# ReactModal Error : NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-modal

I keep getting the error every time I open multiple times of modal and then close it. However, if I was commenting on the API endpoint where I fetch the data the issue doesn't exist everytime I close the modal. I would like to have a dynamic element in the modal however the error exists in fetching data even though I receive the proper data that I want to receive in it.

```
const handleClickManageGrades = async (e, studentId, classSubjectId) => {

e.stopPropagation();

try {
  setIsProcessing(true);
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // STARTING FROM THIS LINE WHEN I TRY TO DO THIS IT ALWAYS GIVE ME A ERROR ABOUT REMOVE CHILD
  // const res = await axios.get(
  //   `/api/student/performance/${classSubjectId}/${studentId}`
  // );
  // console.log(res);

  // END OF ERROR
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  openModal();
} catch (error) {
  toast.error(error);
} finally {
  setIsProcessing(false);
}
  };
```

HERE IS THE RETURN FUNCTION:

```
  return (
        <div>
          <GridComponent
            id="grid"
            dataSource={studentsClassDataManager}
            toolbar={toolbar}
            allowPdfExport={true}
            allowPaging={true}
        toolbarClick={toolbarClick}
        ref={(g) => (grid = g)}
        allowSorting={true}
        allowFiltering={true}
        pageSettings={pageOptions}
      >
        <ColumnsDirective>
          <ColumnDirective
            field="subject_id"
            headerText="Subject Code"
            width="100"
            textAlign="Left"
          />
          <ColumnDirective
            field="student_name"
            headerText="Name"
            width="130"
            textAlign="Left"
          />
          <ColumnDirective
            field="class_name"
            headerText="Class"
            width="100"
            filterBarTemplate={templateOptions}
            textAlign="Left"
          />
          <ColumnDirective
            field="semester"
            headerText="Semester"
            width="90"
            filterBarTemplate={semesterOptions}
            textAlign="Left"
          />

          <ColumnDirective
            field="batch"
            headerText="Batch"
            width="90"
            format="C2"
            textAlign="Left"
          />
          <ColumnDirective
            field="student_id"
            headerText="Performance Management"
            width="150"
            template={(rowData) => (
              <button
                // This should open modal with data of the student
                onClick={(e) =>
                  handleClickManageGrades(
                    e,
                    rowData.student_id,
                    rowData.class_subject_id
                  )
                }
                disabled={rowData.isGradeFinalized}
                className={`btn-primary px-3 ${
                  rowData.isGradeFinalized && 'opacity-60'
                }`}
              >
                Manage Grades
              </button>
            )}
          />
        </ColumnsDirective>
        <Inject services={[Sort, Filter, Page, PdfExport, Toolbar]} />
      </GridComponent>

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onRequestClose={closeModal}>
        <button className="float-right text-2xl" onClick={closeModal}>
          <MdOutlineCancel />
        </button>
      </Modal>

      {isProcessing && <Processing text="Getting the scores" />}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: In Modal, is there any other component except `button`?

Comment: Yes, there is more component that exists in it. But I trying to remove some of it currently so I can see where the error begins and I found out that the error is existing everytime I fetch the data. It always exists everytime I close the modal.